# Некорректная работа js скриптов на iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone

На устройствах iphone в разных браузерах не работают некоторые js скрипты (это видно по внешнему виду страницы). Есть ли какие-то единые перечни свойств, функций, которые могут некорректно отрабатывать на айфонах? Есть ли браузеры на компьютер, в которых есть такие же проблемы (чтобы можно было посмотреть консоль на предмет ошибок)? Есть ли программы/браузеры, которые полностью воспроизводят поведение айфона с доступом к консоли на windows 10? Что можно еще посмотреть в такой ситуации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в регулярном выражении. Оказывается, на iphone в браузерах не поддерживается ретроспективная проверка. Проверяли на 11-ом и ниже.

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, что такие проблемы случаются на устройствах **ниже iOS 13**, то есть на iPhone 5 5s 6. Потому что они написали, чтобы исправить все проблемы в браузерах, и я не видел проблемы, когда iOS 13 была актуальна. Полный список конфликтующих функций и событий, я думаю, найти проблемавато. Есть сайты эмулятора для устройств [live.browserstack.com](https://live.browserstack.com) и [appetize.io](https://appetize.io), на них можно протестировать свой сайт. Если у вас сайт локальный, тогда разместите его в [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com), я тоже так тестировал на iPhone свой сайт

Answer (score 2):

Если я вас правильно понял вам нужно посмотреть консоль через iphone для того ,чтобы проверить ,что именно вызывает ошибку.

Если это так то вы можете подгрузить вот этот скрипт на ваш сайт https://github.com/liriliri/eruda

Eruda эта javascript код который добавляет кнопку "просмотра кода элемента" на разных устройствах.

Вот демо-страница этого кода https://eruda.liriliri.io . Как вы можете заметить, слева снизу есть кнопка "настроек" она и откроет вам консоль и весь код страницы. На этой странице вы можете проверить работает ли этот скрипт в вашем браузере или нет.
[image]

**Стоит помнить , что если вы хотите посмотреть ошибки ваших скриптов ,то этот скрипт eruda  нужно выполнить перед вашими скриптами.**